# F10 and F11 not working at VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

VS2013 <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> features is not working by default .Instead, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> works for the same functionality. I recently installed DevExpress. Default Programming Language is C# selected. What might cause this issue ?

Comment: fn? Notebook user? Perhaps is the default behavior of your model? Which model?

Comment: Ye, it looks like your computer just sends some shortcuts instead of using the Fn keys. Try to look in the control panel to change the behavior.

Comment: HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC

Answer (score 0):

http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108 I changed the BIOS settings of notebook following the steps on the link then it works ...